# Finite index extension and amenable commensurated subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a countable group, $H$ a finite index subgroup of $G$. If $H$ has an infinite amenable commensurated subgroup, then so does $G$?

I know that if $H$ has an amenable normal subgroup $N$, then $G$ has an amenable normal subgroup containing $N$.

Comment: Every group has $\{1\}$ as amenable commensurated subgroup. Do you mean "has an infinite amenable commensurated subgroup"?

Comment: Yes, I mean "infinite amenable commensurated". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample showing that $G$ need not have an infinite amenable commensurated subgroup, even if its index $2$ subgroup $H$ has one.

Let $A_0$ and $A_1$ be two copies of a cyclic group of prime order $p\geq 3$, and let $\alpha$ be an involutive automorphism of the free product $B=A_0\ast A_1$ that swaps $A_0$ with $A_1$. Let $F$ be a free group on two generators, and take $H$ to be the (restricted, regular) wreath product $H=B\wr F=(\bigoplus _F B)\rtimes F$, viewed as an internal semidirect product, so that $\bigoplus _F B$ and $F$ are subgroups of $H$. Let $\tilde{\alpha}$ be the automorphism of $H$ that fixes all elements of $F$ and that restricts to the automorphism of $\bigoplus _F B$ that acts as $\alpha$ on each $F$-coordinate. Then $H$ is an index $2$ subgroup of $G=H\rtimes \langle \tilde{\alpha}\rangle$.

The subgroup $\bigoplus _F A_0$ is an infinite amenable commensurated subgroup of $H$, so it remains to show that if $C$ is an amenable commensurated subgroup of $G$, then $C$ is finite.

After intersecting with $H$, we can assume that $C$ is contained in $H$. The image of $C$ in $F$ under the retraction $H\rightarrow F$ (with kernel $\bigoplus _F B$) is a commensurated amenable subgroup of $F$, hence trivial. So $C$ must be contained in $\bigoplus _F B$. For $g\in F$ let $p_g :\bigoplus _F B\rightarrow B$ be projection to the $g$-coordinate. Then $p_g (C)$ is a commensurated amenable subgroup of $B=A_0\ast A_1$, so it is finite and conjugate into either $A_0$ or $A_1$. If toward a  contradiction $C$ is infinite, then there is some $g\in F$ for which the group $D:=p_g (\tilde{\alpha} ^{-1}(C)\cap C )$ is nontrivial. But then there is some $w\in B$ and $i\in \{ 0, 1 \}$ with $wA_iw^{-1}=D\leq p_g(C)$ and $\alpha (w)A_{1-i}\alpha (w)^{-1}=\alpha (D)\leq p_g(C)$, so in fact $D$ and $\alpha (D)$ generate all of $B$, contradicting that $p_g(C)$ is amenable and $B$ is not.

---

On the positive side, I believe the following holds in general: the property of "containing an infinite commensurated finitely generated nilpotent subgroup" is inherited from finite index subgroups. The proof I have in mind is a bit long but not too difficult (though I would guess that this likely follows easily from some known published results).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
Could you tell me the proof of what you write in the last part?